# What does "this" refer to inside a function in an "on.." attribute?

Tags: javascript

For example, what is the difference between `<td  id='xyz' onmouseover='doIt(this)'...`
and  `<td  id='xyz' onmouseover='doIt()'...`.  Is `this` the DOM element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example, `this` refers to the DOM element the handler is bound to. I recommend to read [the excellent articles at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html), which explains this and much more about event handling.

> what is the difference between `<td id='xyz' onmouseover='doIt(this)'...` and `<td id='xyz' onmouseover='doIt()'...`

In the first case you are passing an argument to the function, which is a DOM element, in the second case you don't.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers invoke constructed handler functions such that `this` refers to the DOM element targeted by the event. Thus, `this` is just a reference to the DOM element on which such an attribute appears.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` will refer to the DOM element, in your example the `td` DOM element.

Have a look at the [MDN page on event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events) for more information, specifically the section on [inline event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events#Inline).

Answer (score 0):

You asked "what is the difference". The difference is that in the first case, the call is made from an execution context where `this` is a reference to the element and that reference is passed to `doIt` as the first parameter. In the second case no parameters are passed.

Now the why.

When an event reaches an element, the related handler will see if there is any code to run. If there is, it will create a new execution context as if in function code with the global object on its scope chain and `this` binding set to the element. It will then execute the code. So within the execution context of the handler, when the code:

```
doIt(this)
```

is executed, `this` references the element. Note that since `this` is not set in the call to `doIt()`, its `this` will either default to the global object in non–strict mode, or remain undefined in strict mode.